# how to Change Font Size of UI Text element using UI Slider in unity C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, unity-game-engine, text

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class slide : MonoBehaviour {

```
Text text;
public Slider slider;

void Start(){

    text = GetComponent<Text> ();

}

public void textscale(int value){

    slider.value     = text.fontSize;

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace your current script with the following one:

   ```
   public class slide : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public Text text; // Drag & drop the Text component inside the Inspector

       public void ChangeFontSize(float value)
       {    
           ChangeFontSize( Mathf.RoundToInt( value ) ) ;
       }

       public void ChangeFontSize(int value)
       {    
           text.fontSize = value;    
       }
   }
   ```
2. Click on your Slider, add a new entry in the `OnValueChanged` event.
3. Drag & drop the gameObject holding the script, and select `slide > ChangeFontSize (Dynamic float)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add script:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

   public class ScalerScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public Text text;

       public void TextScale(Slider slider)
       {
           text.fontSize = (int)slider.value;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create empty GameObject. Attach `ScalerScript` to it and drag and drop your Text object to Text field of the script in the Inspector window:

[image]

[image]

3. Set `Vertical Overflow` to `Overflow` for your Text element:
   [image]
4. Set up Slider. Drag and drop empty GameObject with ScalerScript attached to `OnValueChanged` slider function. Drag and drop Slider element as a parameter to TextScale method. Set Slider's `MaxValue` to 200:

[image]

5. Run the scene.